# How to remove UIView or UIButton from superview inside UIScrollView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uibutton

I did following code to add UIView and UIButton as tags inside UIScrollView. Everything is working fine to append data into UIScrollView. Problem is how to remove UIView & UIButton inside UIScrollView. I did to remove but it does not disappear from UI. Please help me how to do.

**Here is to create UIView & UIButton as tags**

```
    var xOffset: CGFloat = 0;
    var i = 0;
    for location in locationNameStrs {
        let myString: NSString = location as NSString
        let size: CGSize = myString.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 13)!])
        outletView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(xOffset, 10, size.width + 40, 40))
        outletView.tag = i
        outletStrs = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 5, outletView.frame.size.width, 25))
        outletStrs.setTitle(location, forState: .Normal)
        outletStrs.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center
        outletStrs.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.00, green:0.45, blue:0.74, alpha:1.0)
        outletStrs.layer.cornerRadius = 12.5
        outletStrs.tag = i
        outletStrs.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.removeTags(_:)), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        outletStrs.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 13)!

        let closeImg = UIImageView (frame: CGRectMake(outletStrs.frame.size.width - 30, 0, 25, 25))
        closeImg.image = UIImage(named: "close")
        closeImg.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.Right
        outletStrs.addSubview(closeImg)
        outletView.addSubview(outletStrs)

        tagScrollView.addSubview(outletView)
        xOffset = xOffset + size.width + 50
        i = i + 1
    }

    tagScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(xOffset + 50, 50)
```

**Here is to remove, but problem is those not disappear from UI**

```
func removeTags(sender: UIButton) {
    let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
        if self.locationNameStrs.contains(self.locationNameStrs[sender.tag]) {
            self.locationNameStrs.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)
            self.outletView.removeFromSuperview()
            self.outletStrs.removeFromSuperview()
            self.closeImg.removeFromSuperview()
            self.addButton.removeFromSuperview()
            self.displayOutletTags()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified with debugger / console output that the `if` branch is indeed executing? Also it doesn't make sense to remove anything but the top-level `outletView`. It will take all of its subviews with it.

Comment: Also the if logic makes no sense because you're asking an array if it contains one of its own members. The only alternative would be for `sender.tag` to be out of bounds which would crash your program.

Comment: @BaseZen can you suggest me how to do?

Comment: Can you put the entire project up on GitHub or whatever is the convention. The problem with UI bugs is there's so many sources of the problem. I can then summarize the answer after fixing it.

Comment: @BaseZen I've found solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the alert API correctly. You're leaving out the essential piece that gets it on the screen -- the View Controller itself. You need:

```
func removeTags(sender: UIButton) {
    let alertBox = UIAlertController(title: "Removing tags", message: "I will now remove some tags.", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
        guard sender.tag < self.locationNameStrs.count else {
            print("Invalid tag index \(sender.tag)!")
            return
        }
        self.locationNameStrs.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)
        self.outletView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.dislayOutletTags()
    }
    alertBox.addAction(okAction)
    self.presentViewController(alertBox, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

**OR**

without the Alert, since it seems you don't want that:

```
func removeTags(sender: UIButton) {
    guard sender.tag < self.locationNameStrs.count else {
        print("Invalid tag index \(sender.tag)!")
        return
    }
    self.locationNameStrs.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)
    self.outletView.removeFromSuperview()
    self.dislayOutletTags()
}
```

You should not be iterating through the scroll view to remove every view you find. This is fragile & awkward design. You're already keeping track of the view added, so remove it by name.

Your `isKindOfClass()` in your solution makes no sense, because by definition a view's subviews are all subclasses of `UIView`.

Again, your `if` statement makes no sense, since you're looking at an item in the array, and asking if that very array contains it.

Comment: Your one does not mention which UIView are gonna be removed.

Comment: It explicitly removes `outletView` as you see right in the code. Everything that has been added as a subview to `outletView` is automatically removed as a result. Try it and see.

Comment: If I render your code, tapped UIView cannot be moved. Other first/last UIView is removed.

Comment: Then you need to track which one was tapped, store it in a class property (`self.outletView` or otherwise), so it can be removed from your `removeTags` method. You haven't given enough context, so you're responsible for fixing up that part yourself. THe answer was just to help you make a proper `UIAlertController` and also to remove the redundancies regarding `isKindOfClass` and `.contains`. The rest you're responsible for, unless you want to post the entire class code in another question. Probably best for the code review forum to get an overall critique.

Answer (score 0):

```
if self.locationNameStrs.contains(self.locationNameStrs[sender.tag]) {
    self.locationNameStrs.removeAtIndex(sender.tag)
    for view in self.tagScrollView.subviews {
        if view.isKindOfClass(UIView) {
            view.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
    self.displayOutletTags()
}
```

Above coding fixed my request.

Comment: There is still bad style and shows some misunderstandings. See the above for how to use an alert controller correctly.